# Sproutcore Database connection

Tags: sqlite, sproutcore

How can I connect the sproutcore datasource to a database backend such as sqlite or mysql ?
How do I connect it to the backend server ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this tutorial: http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12413071/Todos%C2%A0Intro and especially this page http://wiki.sproutcore.com/w/page/12413058/Todos%2007-Hooking%20Up%20to%20the%20Backend